# Solana Token Swap Program

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

I am trying to create a swap pool and interact with existing pools to perform a swap by interacting with solana swap program but getting this error.
"Program log: panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', token-swap/program/src/state.rs:61:17",
full log:

```
logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4497 of 800000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 790060 compute units',
    'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
    'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 783597 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 779714 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20307 of 795503 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
    'Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Init',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4492 of 764016 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    "Program log: panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0', token-swap/program/src/state.rs:61:17",
    'Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw consumed 18624 of 775196 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked',
    'Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
```

I tried everything I could, manually created and funded the token accounts owned by the program but to nothing

Comment: There's likely a mismatch between the client you're using and the program you're sending to.  Most active deployments are against version 3.0.0, so be sure you also build your client against that: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/releases/tag/token-swap-v3.0.0

Comment: yeah its version 3.0.0 only

Comment: I had the same issue and I figured it out, check the answer here : https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/solana-token-swap-program-program-log-panicked-at-index-out-of-bounds-the-l/6103#6103